# Can devops tags and statuses be specific/unique for each project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

our devops handles very disaprate projects.  Some are platform based like salesforce enhancements, webpage builds, software, processes like the fiscal year channel partner updates and agreements (legal).  Each type of project would benefit from their own group of tags and statuses.  is that possible? or will all have to share the same common pool of tags?

Answer (score 0):

Tags and work item templates are set at the Project level. If you want distinct tags for anything related to say Salesforce, create a Salesforce project and manage the work items related to Salesforce in that project.

Users can be members of multiple projects, and a project can have 1 or more teams.